# last-child and nth-child with IE7 and IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Ok so I need to add a background color to the last row in the all the tables except the last table where I need to add a background color to the last three rows.

```
table tbody tr:last-child    
table:last-child tbody tr:nth-last-child(-n+3)
```

How do I make this work in IE7 and IE8?

Preferably a CSS-only solution. Will a solution like Modernizr solve this? I prefer not to travers the dom with jQuery and add custom classes/styles with my own script.

Comment: Have you considered putting the last 3 rows in a `<tfoot>` element?

Answer (score 2):

short answer: no to a css-only solution;

modernizr isn't going to give the css engine in old ie any additional features.  Your best bet is to either **a)** add classes to the rows you want styled differently or **b)** do it with javascript.  If you are generating the tables dynamically (with php, for example) then adding classes there is easier.

Answer (score 2):

CSS-only solution not possible, you are dealing with browsers that are way too old. On the upside, you don't need your own script as [Selectivzr](http://selectivizr.com/) does just this, or alternatively the all-in-one solution that is [IE9.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) (fixes a ton of other IE bugs, not just add new selectors).